# Using pythonanywhere's MySQL DB in python

Tags: mysql, pyodbc, pythonanywhere

I've created a MySQL DB on [pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com). Now I'm writing a python script on my local PC trying to connect to it, but can't establish a connection.

```py
import pyodbc

with pyodbc.connect(DRIVER="{MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver}",
                    SERVER="******.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com",
                    DATABASE="******$default",
                    USER="******",
                    PASSWORD="******",
                    OPTION="3") as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Same with this connection string format:

```py
pyodbc.connect("""DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};SERVER=******.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com;DATABASE=******$default;USER=******;PASSWORD=******""")
```

****** = censored username and password

It returns this error:

> pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Can't connect to > MySQL server on '******.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com' (10060) (2003) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL > server on '******.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com' (10060) (2003)")

[The official documentation](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingMySQL/) doesn't seem to tackle this problem. It only mentions the library **mysqlclient** but I can't find out what it's purpose is.

**Edit:** It's only possible via ssh/paid account [Accessing your MySQL database from outside PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/)

Comment: Please consider posting your update as an answer to make it easier for others to find the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just did so.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer on the site. It's only possible via ssh/paid account [Accessing your MySQL database from outside PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/)

Comment: Did you buy the plan or did you host it somewhere else? I am in the same situation right now and I am trying to find a Python Flask-capable Webhost which supports pyodbc for free, as my project is a demo currently.